# store the progress of progress bar in database using javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

i have multiple checkboxes, onclick the it upgrades the progress bar, and have a submit button , when it will b clicked the updated progress should get stored.

Like this i have two different chapters, in each one it contains 10 topics and each one is having their individual progress bar, and then each one have some tasks with check box, if checkbox is checked progress will get increased and for that particular chapter also progress will increase and then overall of both the chapter's progress will also increase.

bt if someone logout without completing the whole process, it should store the progress upto whatever percent it has been done, for individual topic as well as overall project and for particular chapter.

rite now it storing the progress but when i log out it not stores and shows where i left.!!

```
$(function() {
    $("#prog").progressbar({

        value: 0,
        max: 96,
       textFormat: "fraction",

    });

    $(".box").on("change", function() {
        var total = 0;

        $(".box:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt($(this).val());
            document.getElementById("e1").value= total; 
            if(total < 96){
            document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML=total+"%";}else{
            document.getElementById("e1").innerHTML="100%";
            }
            e1.innerHTML = e1.innerHTML +"<input type='hidden' name='seb' value="+total+">";
        });

        $("#prog").progressbar("value", total);
    });

});
```

Comment: Do you post to a server at some point?

Comment: yes...using php mysql post method i stored it in my database

Comment: the issue is now solved....can anybody plz help me, at the place of 0, i want to show the already stored value in database on progress bar....what modification sholud i do in my javascript ??